# Dask delayed object of unspecified length not iterable error when combining dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, dask, dask-delayed

I'm trying to construct a dictionary in parallel using dask, but I'm running into a `TypeError: Delayed objects of unspecified length are not iterable`.

I'm trying to compute `add`, `subtract`, and `multiply` at the same time so the dictionary is constructed faster.

Here is some code that is representative of my use case:

```
import dask
from dask.delayed import delayed

x1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
x2 = {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}

@delayed
def add(d1, d2):
    z = {}
    z['func1_a'] = d1['a'] + d2['a']
    z['func1_b'] = d1['b'] + d2['b']
    z['func1_c'] = d1['c'] + d2['c']
    return z

@delayed
def subtract(d1, d2):
    z = {}
    z['func2_a'] = d1['a'] - d2['a']
    z['func2_b'] = d1['b'] - d2['b']
    z['func2_c'] = d1['c'] - d2['c']
    return z

@delayed
def multiply(d1, d2):
    z = {}
    z['func3_a'] = d1['a'] * d2['a']
    z['func3_b'] = d1['b'] * d2['b']
    z['func3_c'] = d1['c'] * d2['c']
    return z

@delayed
def last_step(d1, d2):
    z = {}
    z.update(add(d1, d2))
    z.update(subtract(d1, d2))
    z.update(multiply(d1, d2))
    return z
```

Finally, when I run:

```
>>> dask.compute(last_step(x1, x2))

<ipython-input-6-1153797c9d18> in final(d1, d2)
      2 def last_step(d1, d2):
      3     z = {}
----> 4     z.update(add(d1, d2))
      5     z.update(subtract(d1, d2))
      6     z.update(multiply(d1, d2))

/Users/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/delayed.py in __iter__(self)
    409     def __iter__(self):
    410         if getattr(self, '_length', None) is None:
--> 411             raise TypeError("Delayed objects of unspecified length are "
    412                             "not iterable")
    413         for i in range(self._length):

TypeError: Delayed objects of unspecified length are not iterable
```

What am I doing wrong here / failing to understand?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `z` object is a dictionary while the result of `add` is a Delayed object.  The update method expects a dictionary.  There is no way for Python to know how to update one dict with an object-that-will-become-a-dict-when-you-call-compute.

In this case I recommend making `z` into a delayed object

```
# z = {}
z = delayed({})
```

z will stop being a dict, it'll be a thing-that-will-become-a-dict. This means that you can no longer check for keys, insert into it with getitem syntax, do any mutable operation like `.update`, etc, but can still call delayed methods on it.  In your case I might use a pure function like `toolz.merge`

Just to set expectations.  Dask.delayed doesn't parallelize totally arbitrary Python code.  You still need to do some work to think about when objects are delayed and what are concrete.