# dask compute dict of delayed functions

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

I would like to parallelize this code:

```
-        "mean": float(zonal_extract.mean().compute()),
-        "min": float(zonal_extract.min().compute()),
-        "max": float(zonal_extract.max().compute()),
-        "sum": float(zonal_extract.sum().compute()),
-        "stddev": float(zonal_extract.std().compute()),
-        "var": float(zonal_extract.var().compute()),
```

This is the first time that I've tried parallelizing something in python which isn't the same function being called over and over. This would be same data, different function.

attempt1

```
from dask import compute, delayed


results = delayed({})
results["mean"] = zonal_extract.mean
results["min"] = zonal_extract.min
results["max"] = zonal_extract.max
results["sum"] = zonal_extract.sum
results["stddev"] = zonal_extract.std
results["var"] = zonal_extract.var
results = compute(results, num_workers=4)  # , scheduler='processes'
results = {k: float(v) for k, v in results.items()}
```

attempt2

```
mean, min, max, sum, stddev, var = compute(
    zonal_extract.mean(),
    zonal_extract.min(),
    zonal_extract.max(),
    zonal_extract.sum(),
    zonal_extract.std(),
    zonal_extract.var(),
    num_workers=4,
)  # , scheduler='processes'
results = {k: float(v) for k, v in dict(mean, min, max, sum, stddev, var).items()}
```

This seems like a simple task but I couldn't find anything that worked. maybe it is because I'm already within a multiprocessing context and the nested threading (this is probably something that doesn't exist but it sounds cool) or something is error:

```
    L = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1056, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 935, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 542, in wrap_future_result
    return future.result(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 445, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 390, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
TypeError: Delayed objects of unspecified length are not iterable

real    0m25.048s
user    0m46.943s
```

edit:

ohhh it is because the delayed function is overwriting joblib's

```
from dask import compute, delayed
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
```

Comment: if someone has 1500 reputation they can create the tag `rioxarray` or `python-rioxarray`

Comment: I feel like this SO question is very similar but I'm not quite understanding it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48728383/dask-delayed-object-of-unspecified-length-not-iterable-error-when-combining-dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@creanion's answer is a good one, but I'd also point out that there shouldn't be a need to wrap the operations like `mean()`, `var()`, `stddev()` etc in `dask.delayed` objects: these are already lazy operations, so you can call `dask.compute()` on them directly.

So a minimal example without the `delayed` wrappers would be:

```py
import dask
import dask.array as da

# Generate some fake data
zonal_extract = da.random.uniform(size=(100,), chunks=10)

summary_stats = {
    "mean": zonal_extract.mean(),
    "std": zonal_extract.std(),
    "var": zonal_extract.var(),
    "min": zonal_extract.min(),
    "max": zonal_extract.max(),
}

# traverse=True is default, but being explicit
summary_stats_computed, = dask.compute(summary_stats, traverse=True)
```

which produces (with my random number rolls):

```py
{'mean': 0.4903848677019127,
 'std': 0.30733105780457826,
 'var': 0.09445237909128101,
 'min': 0.000996718178509548,
 'max': 0.9981326789252434}
```

Answer (score 1):

`dask.compute` will recurse into dicts for you.

You can write it like the following:

```py
results = dict(
    mean=dask.delayed(zonal_extract.mean)(),
    min=dask.delayed(zonal_extract.min)()
    # and more
)

results = dask.compute(results)[0]
```

The basic idea is that you can have delayed computations nested into tuples, lists, dicts etc that you pass to `dask.compute`. What was needed here was just to make full-fledged delayed objects out of the function calls.

We can be more “efficient” in terms of not repeating ourselves:

```py
computations = {k: dask.delayed(getattr(zonal_extract, k))()
                for k in "mean min max sum std var".split()}
results = dask.compute(computations)[0]
```

If I take a step back, I guess it looks like this parallelization is on a too low level - these are all aggregations that are that are not so intense in arithmetic operations, and they all traverse the same data to do it. `var` is just the square of the `std`, which is even more trival to speed up in that sense.

Comment: I believe that `.min()` and the other class methods might already be dask delayed functions within rioxarray even though they look the same as pandas, they need to have `.compute()` called on them to be evaluated. but I agree with everything you said. It seems like performance is much better with single-thread rasterio and I should parallelize across data (splitting up zones) instead of by function. Dask/rioxarray took up 38x more CPU time and 2x more realtime compared to single-thread rasterio in my zonal stats case (but I think rioxarray could process much larger files if I ran out of RAM)

Answer (score 0):

The main issue was that I was importing two things with the same function name. Changing this

```
from dask import compute, delayed
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
```

to this

```
import dask
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
```

then the second attempt code started working

```
    mean, min, max, sum, stddev, var = dask.compute(
        zonal_extract.mean(),
        zonal_extract.min(),
        zonal_extract.max(),
        zonal_extract.sum(),
        zonal_extract.std(),
        zonal_extract.var(),
        num_workers=3,
    )

    results = {
        k: float(v)
        for k, v in dict(
            mean=mean, min=min, max=max, sum=sum, stddev=stddev, var=var
        ).items()
    }
```

but if someone has a way to actually use dicts with dask and not name things three times I will gladly accept that answer