# Dask looping over library function call

Tags: python, arrays, dask, dask-delayed

#### Goal

I would like to parallelize a loop with dask that uses a [library](https://github.com/ecjoliver/marineHeatWaves) function inside the loop. This function, `mhw.detect()`, calculates some statistics on a slice of a numpy array. None of the slices of the array depend on the other slices, so I was hoping that dask could be used to compute them in parallel and store them all in the same output array.

#### Code

The flow of the code I am working on is:

```py
import numpy as np
import marineHeatWaves as mhw
from dask import delayed

# Create fake input data
lat_size, long_size = 100, 100
data = np.random.random_integers(0, 30, size=(10_000, long_size, lat_size))  # size = (time, longitude, latitude)
time = np.arange(730_000, 740_000)  # time in ordinal days

# Initialize an empty array to hold the output
output_array = np.empty(data.shape)

# loop through each pixel in the data array
for idx_lat in range(lat_size):
    for idx_long in range(long_size):
        # Extract a slice of data
        data_slice = data[:, idx_lat, idx_long]
        # Use the library function to calculate the stats for the pixel
        # `library_output` is a dictionary that has a numpy array inside it
        _, library_output = delayed(mhw.detect)(time, data_slice)
        # Update the output array with the calculated values from the library
        output_array[:, idx_lat, idx_long] = library_output['seas']
```

#### Previous efforts

When I run this code I get the error `TypeError: Delayed objects of unspecified length are not iterable`. [Another stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48728383/dask-delayed-object-of-unspecified-length-not-iterable-error-when-combining-dict) discusses this issue and resolves the issue by converting the output of the delayed function to a delayed object. However, because I didn't create the output object myself I am not sure if I can convert it to a delayed object.

I've also tried wrapping the last line in `da.from_delayed()`, as in `output_array[:, idx_lat, idx_long] = da.from_delayed(library_output['seas'])` and initalizing the `output_array` with `da.empty(data.shape)`. I get the same error, though, since I think the code doesn't make it past the line with the library function `delayed(mhw.detect)(time, data_slice)`.

Is it possible to parallelize this? Is this approach of asking dask to compute all the slices in parallel and put them together in an output array even a reasonable approach?

### Full Traceback

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/rwegener/mhw-ocetrac-census/notebooks/ejoliver_subset_MUR.ipynb Cell 44' in <cell line: 10>()
     13 data_slice = data[:, idx_lat, idx_long]
     14 # Use the library function to calculate the stats for the pixel
---> 15 _, point_clim = delayed(mhw.detect)(time_ordinal, data_slice)
     16 # Update the output array with the calculated values from the library
     17 output_array[:, idx_lat, idx_long] = point_clim['seas']

File ~/.conda/envs/dask/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/delayed.py:581, in Delayed.__iter__(self)
    579 def __iter__(self):
    580     if self._length is None:
--> 581         raise TypeError("Delayed objects of unspecified length are not iterable")
    582     for i in range(self._length):
    583         yield self[i]

TypeError: Delayed objects of unspecified length are not iterable
```

### Update

Using `.apply_along_axis()` as suggested:

```
# Create fake input data
lat_size, long_size = 100, 100
data = np.random.randint(0, 30, size=(10_000, long_size, lat_size))  # size = (time, longitude, latitude)
data = dask.array.from_array(data, chunks=(-1, 100, 100))
time = np.arange(730_000, 740_000)  # time in ordinal days

# Initialize an empty array to hold the output
output_array = np.empty(data.shape)

# define a wrapper to rearrange arguments
def func1d(arr, time, shape=(10000,)):
   print(arr.shape)
   return mhw.detect(time, arr)

res = dask.array.apply_along_axis(func1d, 0, data, time=time)
```

With the output:

```
(1,)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/homes/metogra/rwegener/mhw-ocetrac-census/notebooks/ejoliver_subset_MUR.ipynb Cell 48' in <cell line: 15>()
     12    print(arr.shape)
     13    return mhw.detect(time, arr)
---> 15 res = dask.array.apply_along_axis(func1d, 0, data, time=time)

File ~/.conda/envs/dask/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/array/routines.py:508, in apply_along_axis(func1d, axis, arr, dtype, shape, *args, **kwargs)
    506 if shape is None or dtype is None:
    507     test_data = np.ones((1,), dtype=arr.dtype)
--> 508     test_result = np.array(func1d(test_data, *args, **kwargs))
    509     if shape is None:
    510         shape = test_result.shape

/homes/metogra/rwegener/mhw-ocetrac-census/notebooks/ejoliver_subset_MUR.ipynb Cell 48' in func1d(arr, time, shape)
     11 def func1d(arr, time, shape=(10000,)):
     12    print(arr.shape)
---> 13    return mhw.detect(time, arr)

File ~/.conda/envs/dask/lib/python3.10/site-packages/marineHeatWaves-0.28-py3.10.egg/marineHeatWaves.py:280, in detect(t, temp, climatologyPeriod, pctile, windowHalfWidth, smoothPercentile, smoothPercentileWidth, minDuration, joinAcrossGaps, maxGap, maxPadLength, coldSpells, alternateClimatology, Ly)
    278     tt = tt[tt>=0] # Reject indices "before" the first element
    279     tt = tt[tt<TClim] # Reject indices "after" the last element
--> 280     thresh_climYear[d-1] = np.nanpercentile(tempClim[tt.astype(int)], pctile)
    281     seas_climYear[d-1] = np.nanmean(tempClim[tt.astype(int)])
    282 # Special case for Feb 29

IndexError: index 115 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

Comment: this is totally a reasonable thing to want to do! have you tried using dask.array and applying the function to each chunk using [`dask.array.map_blocks`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.array.map_blocks.html)? also, if you could post the full traceback that really helps us debug. thanks!

Comment: since your data is size (10000, 100, 100) and you're compute rather than memory bound, I'd use chunks of something smaller, e.g. (-1, 10, 10) or something. the data is small, but since the function takes meaningful time to run (just under a second for each time series by my count) you're going to want to thow all the cores you can at this rather than optimizing based on chunk size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using delayed, this seems like a good case for dask.array.

You can create the dask array by partitioning the numpy array:

```py
da = dask.array.from_array(output_array, chunks=(-1, 10, 10))
```

Now you can call `mhw.detect` using [`dask.array.map_blocks`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.array.apply_along_axis.html) alongside [`np.apply_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) within each block:

```py
# define a wrapper to rearrange arguments
def func1d(arr, time):
   return mhw.detect(time, arr)

def block_func(block, **kwargs):
    return np.apply_along_axis(func1d, 0, block, **kwargs)

res = data.map_blocks(block_func, meta=data, time=time)
res = res.compute()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This seems like just what I want!
When I run this I get an index error, which seems to be because `func1d` is being passed a small array - `arr.shape` is `(1,)` when called from inside `func1d` and I expect `(10000,)`. I'm wondering if I need to pass in `shape`, as suggested in [the docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.array.apply_along_axis.html), but I can't get the syntax to recognize `shape` as an argument.  Do you know how I can do that, or have any other ideas why the sliced array `arr` is so small?

Comment: did you make sure to use chunks of *negative 1* in the time dimension? that makes the chunk size equal the size of the array, as opposed to a chunk size of 1 :)

Comment: Unfortunately I am doing that already.
I posted what I am doing with the full traceback in the original post. The line of the traceback `if shape is None or dtype is None:` seems really suspicious to me, since it says in the `dask.array.apply_along_axis()` docs "If either of dtype or shape are not provided, Dask attempts to determine them by calling func1d on a dummy array.". I'm not sure, though, because I haven't been able to get the `shape` argument to work.
Thanks for all your help either way. It's all helpful.

Comment: wow - yeah sorry about that! dask.array.apply_along_axis doesn't work the same way as numpy's version at all. not sure what's going on there. I've edited the answer so hopefully it actually works for you.

Answer (score 1):

The map_blocks answer above works great! Additionally, `apply_along_axis()` was suggested and discussed in comments.  I was able to get that method to work, but in order for it to function properly you need to use both the `dtype` and `shape` inputs to `da.apply_along_axis()`. If these aren't supplied the function can't figure out the shape of the data it should pass as an argument.
So, another solution:

```py
import dask.array as da

# Create fake input data
lat_size, long_size = 100, 100
data = da.random.random_integers(0, 30, size=(1_000, long_size, lat_size), chunks=(-1, 10, 10))  # size = (time, longitude, latitude)
time = np.arange(730_000, 731_000)  # time in ordinal days

# define a wrapper to rearrange arguments
def func1d(arr, time):
   return mhw.detect(time, arr)

result = da.apply_along_axis(func1d, 0, data, time=time, dtype=data.dtype, shape=(1000,))
result.compute()
```